# Problem in Mongoose $lookup for nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose that I have the following three collections:

```
product: [
    {
        _id: ObjectId('p1'),
        name: 'Box1'
    }
]

// ----------

order: [
    {
        _id: ObjectId('o1'),
        productId: ObjectId('p1'),
        quantity: 10
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('o2'),
        productId: ObjectId('p1'),
        quantity: 20
    }
]

// ----------

status: [
    {
        _id: ObjectId('s1'),
        orderId: ObjectId('o1'),
        title: 'in-progress'
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('s2'),
        orderId: ObjectId('o2'),
        title: 'succeeded'
    }
]
```

I need to join these three to get following result:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('p1'),
    name: 'Box1',
    order: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId('o1'),
            quantity: 10,
            status: {
                _id: ObjectId('s1'),
                title: 'in-progress'
            }
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId('o2'),
            quantity: 20
            status: {
                _id: ObjectId('s2'),
                title: 'succeeded'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Actually the problem is inside the `order` array which has 2 objects in it to correlate with the relevant `status` collection.

Here what I did something like:

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'order',
            localField: 'productId',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'product.order'
        },
    },

    {
        $lookup: {
            ???   // Make status inside each element of order array
        },
    },
]);
```

Does anyboady have idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer:

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
            from: 'order',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'productId',
            as: 'orders'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$orders'
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'status',
            localField: 'orders._id',
            foreignField: 'orderId',
            as: 'orders.status'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$orders.status'
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            name: {
                $first: '$name'
            },
            order: {
                $push: '$orders'
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Then result would be something like this:

```
[{
    _id: ObjectId('p1'),
    name: 'Box1',
    order: [{
            _id: ObjectId('o1'),
            productId: ObjectId('p1'),
            quantity: 10,
            status: {
                _id: ObjectId('s1'),
                orderId: ObjectId('o1'),
                title: 'in-progress'
            }
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId('o2'),
            productId: ObjectId('p1'),
            quantity: 20,
            status: {
                _id: ObjectId('s2'),
                orderId: ObjectId('o2'),
                title: 'succeeded'
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to `$unwind` the result of the first lookup so that you can consider each separately, do a `$lookup` from the status collection on `orderId`, and then `$group` by the product `_id` and `$push` the orders back into an array.